# jest test fails -> Test suite failed to run : �PNG SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

Tags: jestjs, enzyme

I started working with monorepo lately and the task given to me is to introduce jest in the current monorepo react project : but when I tried running a very basic test the test start failing with following error :

```
 ● Test suite failed to run

/Users/sumitverma/Desktop/prj-web/packages/prj-components/src/assets/images/videoThumbnail.png:1
�PNG


SyntaxError: Invalid or unexpected token

  3 | import classnames from 'classnames';
> 5 | import VideoPlaceholder from 'itComponent/assets/images/videoThumbnail.png';
    | ^
  6 | import FontIcon from '../../atoms/FontIcon';
  7 | 
  8 | const placeHolderContainerClass = classnames('full-width', 'full-height', 'd-flex', 'justify-content-center', 'align-items-center');
```

after which I did a bit googling and found a solution (which was to mock them with a custom file [click here][1])

which I did and my jest.config.js looks like below :-

```
const packageName = 'prj-tick';

module.exports = {
  rootDir: '../../',
  name: packageName,
  displayName: packageName,
  roots: [`<rootDir>/packages/${packageName}`],

  moduleNameMapper: {
    moment: 'moment/moment.js',
    'itComponent/(.*)': '<rootDir>/packages/prj-components/src/$1',
    '\\.(css|less|scss|gif|jpg|svg)$': 'identity-obj-proxy',
    tstyles: '<rootDir>/packages/prj-styles-next/scss',
    '\\.(png)$':'<rootDir>/assetsTransformer.js'
  },
  moduleDirectories: ['node_modules', `<rootDir>/packages/${packageName}/app`, `<rootDir>/packages/prj-components/src`]
};
```

and my assetsTransformer.js does what it supposed to :-

> const path = require('path');
>
> module.exports = {   process(src, filename, config, options) {
> return 'module.exports = ' + JSON.stringify(path.basename(filename)) + ';';   }, };

still the problem persists and I cant find any solution to this... did someone faced the same issue.
[1]: https://github.com/facebook/jest/issues/2663

Answer (score 4):

I found the issue, that's in the sequence of the moduleNameMapper object.
Basically, putting

```
'\\.(png)$':'<rootDir>/assetsTransformer.js'
```

at the top of the object (basically making it first key) solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 1):

I, personally, just use `identity-obj-proxy` for styles and simply mock my img files, like this:

```
module.exports = {
    moduleNameMapper: {
        "\\.(jpg|jpeg|png|svg)$": "<rootDir>/__mocks__/fileMock.js",
        "\\.(css|less|scss|sass)$": "identity-obj-proxy"
    },
}
```

where `fileMock.js` is just an empty `module.exports = {}`.

Comment: Yes, even I tried that.. but It doesnt work in my case.

Comment: sorry fot the late reply...but..yes I am getting the same error.. I am managing this in on monorepo.. and I am writing test for one of the packages inside it. I tried mocking png in both of the places of jest.config.js( one at root level and one at package level) but no luck till yet.

Comment: Actualy the issue was that I was requiring the image from different package.

Comment: You mean outside your `<rootDir>`?

Comment: My RootDir has a 'packages' directory and this directory contains all the packages needful for my app to work.. and I was writing test for one of the package (inside the directory 'packages') and inside this testing package I was requiring a '.png' file which was in other package (under the same packages directory).